# Least squares fit to a an exponential equation with one unknown

Tags: exponential-function, least-squares

I have this equation

$$y = s - cx^{1.85}$$

where *s* is a known integer and c is unknown.  I want to use the least squares method to find the best value of *c* that fits a set of points.

I've used $\sum (log y) - 1.85\sum(log x)\over n$ and used that as an exponent to *e* to be *c*, but doesn't seem correct.

How can I use least squares to determine the variable *c*?

Comment: One approach might be to estimate $c$ with $$\frac1n\sum_i \frac{s-y_i}{x_i^{1.85}}$$ but it rather depends on what you are trying to find the least squares of.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion Henry, but the value of c seems to turn out too low.  What do you mean by 'it rather depends on what you are trying to find the least squares of'?

Comment: @oorst: Can you post all of the details or is it too much data?

Comment: There's not a lot of data, but theres a few small sets that only relate to each other.  Some background: I'm trying to write a graphing app for hydraulic pressure and flow rates.  I've been given a few examples where a line of best fit is drawn by hand to two or three points (flowrate, pressure) on a semi log graph where the x axis intervals are raised to 1.85.  The 1.85comes from something called the Hazen Williams equation.  The points do generally fall pretty closely to this curve.  I just want to figure out that variable for various drawing purposes.

Comment: Can you refactor the problem, by taking the s to the other side and taking logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me put it in a more general form.

You have a model $$y=s -c x^a$$ and a set of $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$ and you need to adjust the parameters in the sense of least squares. This means that you want to minimize $$F=\sum_{i=1}^n\big( s-c x_i^a-y_i\big)^2$$ with respect to the parameters. As usual, you will write the partial derivatives with respect to each parameter and set all of them equal to $0$. The model will be nonlinear if parameter $a$ has to be adjusted and this would require nonlinear regression.

In the case of the post, where $s$ and $s$ are fixed, the problem is simple since $$\frac{dF}{dc}=-2\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^a\big(s-c x_i^a-y_i\big)=0$$ Expanding the sum and grouping terms, we then arrive to $$c=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^a(s-y_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^{2a}}$$

You could have made life simpler defining $z_i=s-y_i$ and $t_i=x_i^a$ which reduces the model to $z=c t$ which would lead to $$c=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n t_i z_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n t_i^{2}}$$ which is the slope of the straight line going through origin when using the transformed variables.

**This is definitely the way I recommend you to use** : start with your $(x_i,y_i)$ values, define the $(t_i,z_i)$ and compute $c$ according to the last formula.

Comment: Thanks Claude.  I haven't done regression for a while and I knew I was probably over complicating things.  Thanks for working it through it too.

Comment: You are welcome ! The problem would be almost as simple if $s$ is unknown but starts to be more complex if $a$ and $s$ are unknown, but it is perfectly doable. If you face the most complex case, let me know and I shall show you how to do it.